# how to create pop up after app.post in node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a form with simple user register like so:

```
<form class="form-inline" action="/" method="post">
      <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="sr-only">Username</label>
                            <input name="username" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Desired Username">
                          </div>
                          <br>
                          <br>
                          <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="sr-only" for="exampleInputEmail3">Email address</label>
                            <input name="email" type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail3" placeholder="Email">
                          </div>
                          <br>
                          <br>
                          <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="sr-only" for="exampleInputPassword3">Password</label>
                            <input name="password" type="password" class="form-control" id="exampleInputPassword3" placeholder="Password">
                          </div>
                          <br>
                          <br>
                          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Register</button>
                        </form>
```

Here is my app.js server side code.

```
app.post('/', function(req, res) {

var user = new Parse.User();
user.set("username", req.body.username);
user.set("password", req.body.password);
user.set("email", req.body.email);

user.signUp(null, {
  success: function(user) {
    // Hooray! Let them use the app now.
    console.log(user);
    res.render('landing', { message: 'Registered' });
  },
  error: function(user, error) {
    // Show the error message somewhere and let the user try again.
    console.log(error.message);
    res.redirect('/#register');


  }
});

});
```

I know that `alert();` doesn't exist on server side of node.js.

im wondering what and how i can have some type of alert for the user to let them know the status of the app.post is.

Comment: are u use body-parser in middleware of express??

Comment: @HimanshuGoyal Yes

Comment: any hit is comes across this '/' url? like you print any console and see the hit is comes on server side??

Comment: u can send respns to front end and then can show alert to user on the basis of response

Comment: you can send back the data to client by res.send()

Comment: @KeyurSakaria how would i handle it client side?

Comment: you can send data to client in JSON format and read it on client by parsing that JSON

Comment: @KeyurSakaria can you give an example?

Comment: Yes, but have you worked with JSON format ?

Comment: Yes but was wondering how to retrieve the res.send()